# Validating presence in Elixir Ecto, but only on insert or update

Tags: elixir, ecto

To validate presence of a parameter, you can add an field to the `required_fields` module attribute in a model.  Then you pass this to the model's `cast` method, which validates that the field is present.

But, what if you only want to validate the presence of something on insert or update?

For example, I only want to validate that a user's password is present if the record isn't persisted.  In other words, I don't want the user to have to supply a password when editing their account info.

The best I've come up with is to have two different sets of required fields for update and insert, and then to have a method pick the appropriate one:

```rb
# in changeset method
cast(params, required_fields(model), @optional_fields)

defp required_fields(model) do
  if Map.has_key?(model, :id) do
    @update_required_fields
  else
    @insert_required_fields
  end
end
```

Is this reasonable, or is there a better way?

### EDIT

Adding in suggestions from @michalmuskala with an addition for a followup question about shared changeset functionality:

```rb
def insert_changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
  model
  |> cast(params, @insert_required_fields, @insert_optional_fields)
  |> shared_changeset
end

def update_changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
  model
  |> cast(params, @update_required_fields, @update_optional_fields)
  |> shared_changeset
end

defp shared_changeset(changeset) do
  changeset
  |> validate_password
  |> unique_constraint(:email)
end
```

Answer (score 6):

The simplest solution is to create two changeset functions - one for insert and one for update. So you would end up with something like:

```
def update_changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
  model
  |> cast(params, @update_required_fields, @optional_fields)
end

def insert_changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
  model
  |> cast(params, @insert_required_fields, @optional_fields)
end
```

And later in the controllers, instead of calling `Model.changeset/2` you'd call `Model.update_changeset/2` or `Model.insert_changeset/2`.

Comment: It seems like you would need insert and update module attributes for both required and optional fields.  I've updated the content of my question a bit for a followup question.  If you took this approach of using two changesets and you had a number of transformations that were shared between inserting and updating, would you then create a shared_changeset private method that both insert and update changeset methods would call?